# Manipulation of Google Graph - show / hide records

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have been looking around for a simple'ish solution that would allowing user to disable certain records on the graph. I know Google Charts API offeres ways to remove columns and rows. However, I don’t want to remove a row, I would like to “disable” it, so that it wouldn’t be used in the calculations, very similar to the google.visualization.ChartRangeFilter, except in ChartRangeFilter you set the date range to focuse on.

i.e. we have a line graph, x and y axis, with three lines for New York, London and Paris. I click on one of the points on the “Paris” line and that would disable that particular point, if I am to click on same point again than it will be enabled once again.

Options that were concidered:

1\ https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#the-select-event to try to "disable" the cell that user would click on.

2\ I have also been thinking to select all records by default and let user unselect them

Wondering if someone has a potential solution?

I found a similar solution, whichI was thinking to utilise, except their you hide / show the lines, rather than particular values..

In the fiddle example they use to make function happen

```
column: 6,
roleColumns: [7],
display: false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/